# Jquery и проблемы с checkbox

Tags: jquery, javascript, checkbox

Сам скрипт работает так, выделяешь категорию, он выделяет все чекбоксы  в ней, снимаешь снимает, но после этого групповое выделение не работает =(.

```
   $('.admin:checkbox').change(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr("id");   
            //alert(name);
            $("input[name='" + name + "']").attr('checked', $('#' + name).is(':checked'));
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то [смотрите этот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/y6GMR/1/)

Comment: Вы просто супер =)!

Comment: @Дартаньян, пока вы не набрали достаточно баллов - не нужно нажимать кнопку "наградить". Голосуете "палец вверх"/"палец вниз" или отмечаете, как правильный ответ, нажав на "галочку" возле ответа.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#' + name).is(':checked') ? 'checked':''  //и далее по тексту.
```

Comment: можно подробней?